# How to use Background Worker ProgressChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, backgroundworker

I need to update the program i did when i was still 3 months in the office. And i found out that the code is not clean and not easy to modify.

What i did is every method is called in background worker. And i created multiply Background worker for each task that possibly be executed at once.

So i am planning in making the code cleaner and easier to maintain.

I created a class and inherit the BackgroundWorker as shown below in my code

```
public class Bgw : BackgroundWorker
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker;
        public int ProcessId { get; set; }
        public object[] ProcessData { get; set; }

        public Bgw(int i, object[] obj)
        {
            ProcessId = i;
            ProcessData = obj;
            worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        public void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ProcessId == 1)
            {
                //executed my code here
            }
        }
    }
```

But with the code above. How can i notify the changes in my controls if i call the class like this

```
var obj = new object[3];
                obj[0] = 1;
                obj[1] = PdfPath;
                obj[2] = EpubPath;
                var work = new Bgw(1, obj);
```

Or is there a better way on doing this? I know that i need to use the ProgressChanged. But how can i Get that changes from where i called that class?

Thank you

Edit: If im going to use async and await like this

```
class Program
{


    public async static void TestAsyncAwaitMethods()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 5000000; i++)
            {
                UpdateUI(i);

            }
        });
    }

    private static void UpdateUI(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Update the UI: " + i);
    }

}
```

ANd call the method TestAsyncAwaitMethods()

How can i update my GUI. When the method reside from a different class and the property i want to update is in another class(I'm using mvvm pattern).

Comment: why don't you use Async and await ? .net team spend lot of time developing it so it worth trying it ! personnally i found bkw outdated...

Comment: Right, if you are planning to rewrite everything, definitely use async/await.

Comment: Hello. Thank you ErwinDraconis and clemens for the answer. I updated the question. My problem now is how can i update the GUI of my application. Thank you. Kindly read the update.

Comment: When using async await you can get help from the `Progress<T>` class. You can create a Report callback where you can update your UI. The tasks, i.e. where you do the work, aren't the ones who actually do the UI update. That'll just make it more complicated for you (due to for instance thread synchronization). So in my opinion, read up on what async await is and how to use it, and also what Progress<T> is

Comment: Thank you default. My problem is i dont know what to search. Then after you mentioned the Progress<T> i searched it. And now the program is working as expected. Thank you so much SO members :)